# Creating Maven assembly with files from different Git branches

Tags: git, maven, jenkins, continuous-integration, git-branch

We are working on a project in which we are using a number of Git branches with different content in each branch. We need to create .zip file using maven plugin in Jenkins with files from different branches. Is there any option available in Jenkins which supports this task?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Simply no. Why do you have files you need on different branches?

Answer (score 0):

I second @khmarbaise's question.

However, it is possible to add more than one branch in a Jenkins job's config via:

*Source Code Management* → *Git* → *Branches to build* → ***Add Branch...***

I tried it with two branches, `branch1` and `branch2`:

- If there are commits pushed to both branches in the remote repo the job runs twice automatically. Each of the runs with one of the two branches checked out.
- If there is no new commit on any of the branches the job runs once with the last configured branch (`branch2`) checked out.
- If there is a new commit on `branch1` only the job runs once with `branch1` checked out.

Now it's up to you to add the files you need to your `.zip`.

If this behaviour of the Jenkins GIT plugin doesn't fit your needs you can:

- Create a project that:

  - checks out `branch1`
  - copies the files you need from `branch1` to a certain directory, e.g. `for-zip`
- Create a second project as downstream of the first that:

  - checks out `branch2`
  - uses ***Build Environment*** → *Copy data to workspace* → *Path to folder:* `<branch1 project's workspace>/for-zip`
  - creates the `.zip`

Instead of copying the needed files from one projects's workspace to the other you can use the [Shared workspace plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Shared+workspace+plugin).